# Does one still fulfill the Mitzvah of Tzitzit even if one didn’t make a Bracha on it?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, mitzvah, tefilin, tzitzis

Is it true that a person still fulfills the Mitzvah of Tzitzit even if they don’t say the Bracha for it? And that would apply to other Mitzvot, such as Tefillin, correct?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Saying a bracha is it's own rule, the mitzva is still fulfilled without it. Source will be easy to find, if someone doesn't beat me to it :)